# What is the easiest way for me to go about rendering (or graphically representing by any means) an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I want to input a matrix (dictionary with a node as the key, and all adjacent nodes in a set as the key [Nodes are represented as integers which are indexes to another dictionary that contains the objects the nodes represent {cells in a maze if anyone is curious}]) and have a graphic that shows the graph with each node labelled, with lines connecting each node.

If there is no convenient way to do this with the format I have posted then it is not too important, but it would be very helpful for my writeup if I could have images of all graphs, and have it ideally done automatically as there will be several in the document.

Python3 btw

I would post the code in question, however, it is part of a larger project for my A-Level Computer Science Coursework and as such has many elements to it.

Comment: Since answer will probably get flagged. Putting this here. https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html).
This python library can help you draw your graphs by just inputting the nodes and edges. 
here are some sample code.

```
pip install networkx #for installing the library
```

for creating a graph

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
```

for adding nodes

```
G.add_node(1)
```

or multiple nodes

```
G.add_nodes_from([2, 3])
```

you can add edge such as

```
G.add_edge(1, 2)
```

and finally to display you can do

```
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

here is a complete sample run

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(
[('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'F'),
 ('B', 'H'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'G')])
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19402358)

Comment: I have incorporated the changes to make answer more up to the standards of stack overflow. I apologise for my laziness shown before.  @FlyingTeller